# Emacs Package management

Tags: emacs, upgrade, package-management

I am a bit confused on exactly how the emacs package management works. I currently run emacs 24.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I just ran the command `package-menu-mark-upgrades` which marks all the packages that have available upgrades. Then I executed to install these upgrades.

However, upon visiting the `.emacs.d/elpa` directory I noticed that the older versions of my installed packages still existed. For example I have two `ess` packages with a bunch of numbers at the end which give the date of their latest build.

Is this typical behavior? Or do I need to run another command to delete these obsolete packages?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I think that is the correct behavior you are seeing -- package manager is not going to delete things on your computer.  This is a good thing, because I frequently modify the sources to custom tailor them to my needs.  Of course, folders have creation / modification dates . . .

Answer (score 1):

That is not the expected behavior. The following is the function documention for `package-menu-mark-upgrade` on GNU Emacs 24.3.1:

> Mark all upgradable packages in the Package Menu.
>   For each installed package with a newer version available, place
>   an (I)nstall flag on the available version and a (D)elete flag on
>   the installed version.  A subsequent M-x package-menu-execute
>   call will upgrade the package.

I can confirm that update a package will delete (or at least attempt to delete) the old version of the package.